# JQuery saving file and reading from it instead of opening new version every time

Tags: jquery

I'm using plain HTML, JS, and JQuery

I'm trying to make a simple high-score system for a game and then move onto a bigger project and so far my high-score system works, it reads and writes to my high-score file if you get a new high-score.
The problem is that whenever I try to open a file it works properly but if I ever try to reopen it after closing then it opens the same version that it did the first time even if the file changed. This only updates when you refresh the page. I need to open the file the first time to display the high-score to players and then another time to read/set it.

This problem means if two players are playing and join at the same time with a score of 0 they will both save this score. Then let's say player one gets a score of 200 and afterward player two gets a score of 100 the final score will be 100 because by the time player two finishes he does not get the updated score of player one and checks against the 0 score, completely ignoring player one score.

I've tried looking this up and using flush and rewind but I can't find any solution that works online.

code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <style>

        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
            function reloadie(){
                // all custom jQuery will go here
                jQuery.get('log.txt', function(data) {
                alert(data);
                //process text file line by line
                //$('#div').html(data.replace('n',''));x
            });
            }
            reloadie();
            setInterval(reloadie,3000);
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need a proper database so you can use transactions.

Comment: Check current score using `ajax` before making an update for it. Or check it into your `php` script. You can also store results in some in-between file, and then update the highscore. There are a lot of options: the main key is to check current highscore exactly before updating it.

Comment: If you want this to work with more than 1 user you either need a file locking scheme or a database with transactions and locking.  Consider an old high of 1,000 and two people scoring 1,100 and 1,200 at roughly the same time.  Which new score gets saved?  This is a "race condition" (see Wikipedia)

Comment: @freeek as i said i cant use something like ajax i don't think. just plain php,js and html. also the problem isn't checking before getting the score i'm already doing that, the problem is that i need to open the file at the start just for a display and im having a problem where it is opening the old data the second time i try opening it even if it updated

Comment: @DaveS In that situation 1,200 would be saved because we would always use the highest score, i don't know what you're suggesting.

Comment: A web server might be handling a dozen update requests at the same time, each triggering a separate execution of your PHP code at the same time, each trying to update the file at the same time.  Both the 1,100 and 1,200 could look like a new high score to two different PHP processes.  Each one tries to update the file with their own new high score, and the 1,200 script finishes first before the 1,100 script which then writes over the file with 1,100.  Race condition.

Comment: _"i cant use something like ajax i don't think"_  if it runs in the browser, you can use AJAX. Check out SQLite3 for a file-based relational database

Comment: @Phil oh, i see why i have to use ajax now, can you help me in doing that? i don't know how to get it or use it.